# Original model is changing when changing the copied data in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, sapui5

I am fetching some data (JSONArray) through an API and saving it in two models and an array variable. I am manipulating data in the array but it is changing the values in the models also. Below are my some code snippets :

```
 onInit : function(){
                this.addmodel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                this.addmodel.setDefaultBindingMode(sap.ui.model.BindingMode.OneWay);
                this.getView().setModel(this.addmodel, "Model");

                this.originalModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                this.originalModel.setDefaultBindingMode(sap.ui.model.BindingMode.OneWay);
                this.getView().setModel(this.originalModel, "OrgModel");

                this.router.attachRoutePatternMatched(this._handleRouteMatched, this);
            },
```

Controller.js :

```
            _handleRouteMatched: function (evt) {
                if (evt.getParameter("name") !== "BookMeal") {
                    return;
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Non_sap_create_requests/odata/MealSelfLocMealType",
                    method: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {

                        that.mCopiedArray = $.extend([], data.value);
                        that.originalModel.setData(data);
                        that.addmodel.setData(data);

                    },
                    error: function (err) {

                    }
                });



            onFromDateSelect: function (oEvent) {

                if (Date.parse(fromDate) === Date.parse(currentDate)) {

                    var tempVal = that.mCopiedArray;
                    tempVal = formatter.mealContsraints(tempVal, currentDate, fromDate, currentTime, "null");
                    that.addmodel.setProperty("/value", tempVal);
                } else {
                    that.addmodel.setProperty("/value", that.originalModel.getProperty("/value"));
                }
            },

        });
    });
```

In the above code I am saving data in the array mCopiedArray and in 2 models - addmodel and originalModel. I am manipulating the data in formatter.js. Changing the data in mCopiedArray is also changing the data in addmodel and originalModel.

formatter.js :

```
        mealContsraints: function (value, currentDate, fromDate, currentTime, meal) {

            if (fromdate === currentdate) {
                while (ln--) {
                    if (value[ln].MealField === "Breakfast") {
                        value.splice(ln, 1);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                ln = value.length;

                if (currentTime > '11:30:00') {
                    while (ln--) {
                        if (value[ln].MealField === "Lunch") {
                            value.splice(ln, 1);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                ln = value.length;

                if (currentTime > '16:30:00') {
                    while (ln--) {
                        if (value[ln].MealField === "Eve Snacks") {
                            value.splice(ln, 1);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (currentTime > '18:00:00') {
                    while (ln--) {
                        if (value[ln].MealField === "Dinner") {
                            value.splice(ln, 1);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.extend([], data.value);` does **not** create a deep copy. So if you modify an item in your array (e.g. change `MealField` from `Dinner` to `Midnight Snack`) it will also be changed in the model.

But if you modify the array itself (e.g. remove an item from the array) that should **not** affect the model.

I did a small snippet for this:

```
const mData = {value: [
    { MealField: "Dinner", id: 3 },
    { MealField: "Lunch", id: 2 },
    { MealField: "Breakfast", id: 1 }
]};

const oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(mData);
const aCopy = $.extend([], mData.value);
aCopy.splice(1, 1);
// arrays should be different
console.log(aCopy);
console.log(oModel.getProperty("/value"));
aCopy[0].MealField = "Midnight Snack";
// single item should be the same
console.log(aCopy[0]);
console.log(oModel.getProperty("/value/0"));
```

So the problem shouldn't be the formatter but something else?

Btw your formatter isn't a formatter. A real formatter should return a value and not have side effects (like modifing models/data).

Answer (score 0):

The objects are working reference logic so you can use jquery.extend().[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to make a deep copy of an object is to serialize it to json and the deserialize it to a new object:

Let objString = JSON.stringfy(obj):
Let newObject = JSON.parse(objString)

PS: that will work for serializable properties and if you have 
A huge object you might run into performance issues.